# Propogate property value in class hierachy

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I want to propagate the property  from child class to parent class, 
ie:  If **MySchool.ModifiedTime** is changed it should change the ModifiedTime in Student Class too, like wise **LstBook[0].ModifiedTime** is changed it should change **MySchool.ModifiedTime** as well **Student.ModifiedTime**... (basically ModifiedTime should be in sync),any Idea

I'm looking for a Generic function in BaseClass to achieve this.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
  public DateTime ModifiedTime{ get; set; }
}

public class Student: MyBaseClass
  {       
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public school MySchool {get;set;} 
 }

public class School : MyBaseClass
{
 public string SchoolName { get; set; }
 public List<Book> LstBook {get;set;}
}

public class Book:MyBaseClass
{
  public string BookName{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you've got several different objects but you want them to all share a single ModifiedTime. That is if someone changes ModifiedTime on the school object, you want the associated Student's ModifiedTime to also change. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, in the same class structure

Answer (score 3):

You could make `ModifiedTime` virtual and then in each child class override it to perform the syncing.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
  public virtual DateTime ModifiedTime{ get; set; }
}

public class Student: MyBaseClass
{       
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public school MySchool {get;set;} 
  public virtual DateTime ModifiedTime
  { 
    get {
       return MySchool.ModifiedTime;
    }
    set {
       MySchool.ModifiedTime = value;
    }
  }
}
```

And so on.

However, I would reconsider your class hierarchy because it seems like the factoring is incorrect. If all the properties need to be in sync across the entire hierarchy then maybe only one class should have that property and other classes should refere to it. For example, only `School` should have the ModifiedTime property and when you need to get the modified time for a student you would retrieve it through the `MySchool` property

Comment: it will work, but i do not want to write this code in each implemented class like (student,school,book).I'm looking for a Generic function in BaseClass to achieve this.

Comment: these are sample classes but in real scenario Book class can be used in Teacher class, so i do not want to nest it..

Comment: I agree, it seems like the object model being worked with is not sufficient to accurately model whatever is really going on.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding how object hierarchy works.

Implementing this as a class member only links it to the object created, and a static method would of course mean all objects access the same property.

Instead, as I understand it, you want groups of instances (not all) to share a property.

The simplest way to do this is to create a shared object that provides the modified time for all instances in a group.

Answer (score 1):

As the other commenters have pointed out, you can't do this in a straightforward way with a base class simply because that's not how class hierarchies work. What you could do is create another class called "GroupInfo" or something like that. Make ModifiedTime a property on that.

In all your other classes, add a property for a GroupInfo. Then whenever you create a new book or whatever, as part of the constructor pass in a reference to the GroupInfo for the book.

That way all the objects in the group will share a single GroupInfo, and thus a single ModifiedTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `ModifiedTime` static, which will cause it to be shared among all derived instances of MyBaseClass.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
  public static DateTime ModifiedTime{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: *More complete example; better explanation of methodology***

Your base class could be better described as a interface since your enforcing that each class implement a common property and not making common calculations or sweeping generalizations that could group schools, students, and books together.

Pursuing an event driven solution there are a few things you can do such as using `BindingList<T>` which is basically `List<T>` on steroids.

Unfortunatly, you'll need to explode your pretty little `{ get; set; }` properties into full fields, but the best way is for each modification of a property to trigger an event. Each subsequent object that is affected by the modification is subscribed to your modified objects `Modified` event.

```
public interface IChangeAware
{
    event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnChange;
    DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IChangeAware
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnChange;
    public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public School School
    {
        get { return School; }
        set 
        {
            School = value; 
            if (this.OnChange != null)
                this.OnChange(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public Student()
    {
        if (School != null)
            School.OnChange += MySchoolOnChange;
    }

    void MySchoolOnChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class School : IChangeAware
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnChange;
    public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }

    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    public BindingList<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public School()
    {
        Books = new BindingList<Book>();
        Books.ListChanged += BooksListChanged;
    }

    void BooksListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now;
        OnChange(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string BookName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ModifiedTime is in baseclass , even if i have an event how can i notify the parent..?,Also I'm looking for a Generic function in BaseClass to achieve this.

Comment: If it's in the base class, any subclass can already see it by simply using the ModifiedTime property.

Comment: @Tridus ok, but then how does an object know it's parent? From what I see here, a book shouldn't need to know which object it is subordinate to in order to pass on a modified timestamp.  A book should emit that it has been changed, and any concerned objects should act accordingly. My example should probably have `ModifiedTime = ((School) sender).ModifiedTime;`, but thats really left up to the implementer.

Comment: @Greg, Thanks for taking time to explore this problem, But what i want is a generic solution like i stated in my question, without changing the class structure.. (i want the code to be in the BaseClass , so that i can keep the implemented class simple...)

Comment: possibly looking for some reflection based solution in baseclass

Comment: @kayak I don't see any good way to modify your baseclass to do this how you envision it. I think you're on the right track with a reflection oriented approach.